# Popover shows when hovering inner iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small issue with a series of non-bootstrap popover made by me that contains social buttons each one and have to be shown when hovering or clicking an element that contains the popover.

The html of one of the items is like this:

```
<li class="social__list-item  js-show-popover">
    <a href="" class="social__link  footer-social__link  footer-social__link--googleplus"></a>
    <div class="media  social__popover">
        <div class="media-left">
            <span class="popover__img"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <p class="popover__title">Síguenos en Google+</p>
            <div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-height="20" data-href="https://plus.google.com/104645458102703754878" data-rel="community"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I am hiding `.social__popover` with `opacity: 0;` and `visibility: hidden;` and turn visible with jquery.

Everything works as expected, the problem is when you hover over the area where the iframe embedded buttons are when the popover is hidden and they make the popover to show.

Using display:none on the popover solves the issue, but it makes to break the rendering of some of those embedded buttons (mainly google buttons)

I prepared a Jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/victorRGS/dcv2g973/1/

It seems that we can live with it but I would like to work as expected, also the area of the facebook widget (not working in the example, idk why) is quite bigger and this one could be a real annoyance.

Any help will be welcome

Comment: Solved using `z-index: -1;` when hidden and `z-index: 10;` when visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this adding the `z-index` property and worked fine, with no behavior problems in touch devices.

Updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/victorRGS/dcv2g973/2/

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your problem right, you should try this.

Adjust `pointer-events:none;` to the popover when they are hidden, and set back to `auto` when you hover the icon.

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/y6Ldjuwd/

Is this what you want?

Comment: That is *exactly* what I was looking for!! Much appreciated!

Comment: After more testing I found this solution is not behaving correctly in touch devices :\

Comment: What happens? Maybe your popover is not working at all on touchscreen devices?

Comment: The popover works, but I have access to those iframe links when the popover is not visible. I have tested with Safari and Chrome in Ipad, and with Chrome and Stock browser in an Android device. 

Caniuse says that it should work.

I am thinking on going for a static version of those buttons, but i will lose the Fb page plugin that looks really nice with this design.

Comment: What you could try is using 'opacity ' in stead of 'visibilty'.

Comment: Oh yeah ofc, I forgot. I think I cant you help you further :( Because I cant test.